# AttributeError: module 'meep' has no attribute 'Vector3' in python3 jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ubuntu-18.04, meep

AttributeError: module 'meep' has no attribute 'Vector3' in python 3 in jupyter notebook and google collab. the error keeps occurring no matter how many times run or uninstalled and installed ubuntu 18.04 again.

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? Like the libraries you have installed in your python environment, etc.

Comment: i have installed meep, jupyter-core, miniconda and its one windows 10 so using ubuntu 18.04